# Using permalinks, category slugs, and tag slugs

Tags: posts, categories, tags, permalinks

I'm trying to set up some permalinks for my site. Right now all the posts are under sitename.com/blog/, which is fine. But the category pages and tag pages show as 'sitename.com/blog/category/catname' and 'sitename.com/blog/tag/tagname'.

Is there a way to just skip the 'category' and 'tag' parts of the URL? As in:
'sitename.com/blog/catname'
'sitename.com/blog/tagname'

I tried leaving the optional settings (Settings --> Permalinks --> Optional) as blank for 'Category base' and 'Tag base', but they default to 'category' and 'tag', which brings me back to my previous problem.

I then tried putting 'blog' instead. It works for the categories and tags, but it then makes all the posts redirect to a 404 page. It's as if it searches for a category/tag with the name of [postname] and on failing to find one, 404s me.

Anyone having this trouble / found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I was messing with my permalinks today for the same reason. And i ended up with a solution that worked great.

You have to change your custom permalink structure to:

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

In the category base field just put a period mark:

```
.
```

and your permalinks will display in this form:

```
CATEGORY PAGE
mysite.com/blog/category-name/

POST PAGE
mysite.com/blog/category-name/post-name/
```

I don't think it works for tags pages though. I tried putting "." in the tag base field the permalink is correct like:

```
TAG PAGE
mysite.com/blog/tag-name/
```

but the page returns error 404. So i guess it doesn't see the page without the default "tag" tag base.

Answer (score 0):

Advanced permalinks plugin might solve your issue

---

[advanced permalinks](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/advanced-permalinks/)